# License to re-publish information created in share point?

Tags: licensing

We have lots of users that don't have computers and never come in to the office, these are people working in the field. We want to create an app that they can use to read some of the information we at the office write in share point. we already have a separate web application they use to read other information not created in share point. Can i write a job that exports information from share point to this other system and legally have our users in the field read this information without any licenses what so ever? They don't even exist in the AD since they never use any corporate network.

Is there somewhere I can read this so I can give it to my boss who thinks we need CAL licenses for these users?

Comment: The content you create is yours, a CAL is for interaction with the application. As you're exporting the data to a different location, its not covered by the CAL. It's no more complex than exporting data from Excel to CSV for use in another system.